# Unable to sync default "Comments" field from Account Engagement to Salesforce

Tags: account-engagement

We're trying to sync the Default "Comments" Field in Account Engagement (Pardot) to Salesforce.  However, when I click "Edit default prospect field", there is no option to add a salesforce.com Field Name to Sync

Has anyone else run into this issue? Would appreciate any help with this!

[image]